# Mercurial: "abort: push would create new anonymous heads (xxxxxxxxx)"

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I'm using Mercurial locally, and pushing to bitbucket.org.  I'm the only person working on this (private) project, and it's almost entirely on this computer, though there are one or two other computers that I've worked on it (ie the server).  This error message is mysterious to me, and there is almost nothing about it on google.  It is similar to the error you get when you haven't pulled/merged, but I have nothing to pull, nor to merge.

What is the cause of this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The error is weird as Mercurial should handles anonymous heads without problems. Are you trying to use hg-git with Mercurial by any chance?

Comment: Ahh, good call, I just realized I am using a modified version of Mercurial internal to our company!  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As lothiraldan pointed out in a comment, it's actually because I am using a weird version of Mercurial internal to my company.

Comment: It's not really an internal version of Mercurial. https://hg-git.github.io/ is a Mercurial extension that let you interact with git repositories from Mercurial. How it does is it create a bookmark for git branches. So the error message you saw is likely when you tried to push your Mercurial head to git and it didn't had a bookmark, so git refused your changeset. Try adding a bookmark and push again.